# Control theory - what method is used to find the discrete time control system here

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control

We are given a car model:
$$\dot x = V\cos(a) \quad
\dot y = V\sin(a) \quad
\dot a = u$$

$V$ some arbitrary number

Make an (first order) approximation
$$\dot x  = V \quad
\dot y = Va \quad
\dot a = u$$

And discretize into:
$$(1) \quad a(k+1) = a(k) + u(k)*T$$
$$(2) \quad y(k+1) = y(k) + a(k)VT + u(k)*0.5V*T^2$$

I can understand how they got the first equation, but how was the second equation derived? Specifically, where did that $0.5$ term come from?

(on a side note, is there a name for discretization of the form $\dot a \approxeq \dfrac{a(k+1) - a(k)}{T}?) $

Comment: The discretization method you use is called "Euler method" or to be more precise "Euler Forward Method". See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations#Euler_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second piece comes from averaging two different discretizations of $\dot{y}$. Namely, we could replace the $a$ in the $\dot{y}=Va$ equation by either $a(k)$ or $a(k+1)$. This gives us two equations: $$y(k+1)=y(k)+a(k)VT$$ and: $$y(k+1)=y(k)+a(k+1)VT$$ Then averaging the two equations yields: $$\frac{y(k+1)+y(k+1)}{2}=\frac{y(k)+a(k)VT+y(k)+a(k+1)VT}{2}$$ Simplifying this equation and substituting the expression for $a(k+1)$ from equation (1) of your question then gives: $$y(k+1)=y(k)+a(k)VT+\frac{u(k)VT^2}{2}$$

As far as I am aware, the process of replacing $\dot{f}$ by $\frac{f(k+1)-f(k)}{T}$ is referred to as discretization.

Comment: It is interesting that you can replace $\dot y = V a$ by either $a(k)$ or $a(k+1)$, totally not obvious actually

Comment: @FenceJumper The reason someone might think to do so is because in replacing $\dot{y}$ you are introducing both a $y(k+1)$ piece and $y(k)$ piece. So why not do the same with $a$?

Comment: The reason for averaging is not that we could use either $a(k)$ or $a(k+1)$. It is due to the fact that integration of $a$ from $k$ to $k+1$. This is exactly the same reason why we get $x = a t^2 / 2$ even though $v = at$ and $x = vt$, as we all learned in high school. (And I think it is extremely hard to explain someone who doesn't know calculus).